How come I haven't been accepted as a reviewer for Physical Review D?
A few months ago, I applied to become a referee in Physical Reviews D. I have seven publications there.
However, I still have not received any update on the status of the application. Could you please tell me if I miss something because of which I may be not eligible?

I don't think I got a request to referee for Physical Review D until I had published about twenty papers there.

@Buzz : I know people who only have two papers but are already referees.

There is no way that we can know whether or not you might, or might not, be eligible

To become a reviewer for Phys. Rev., it is usually enough that someone who is already a reviewer there recommends you. Whenever I get some article for review which I have no time to review or don't feel it is in my area of expertise, I can recommend an alternative reviewer. The editors usually follow these recommendations, and they are very interested in extending their pool of reviewers. You can just ask your former or current PI to forward you some papers in this way, and then you will start getting new submissions from the journal.
Edit: I recommend that you check your account at referees.aps.org and see if it shows you as "available for review" and also contains enough keywords under "Expertise" to make sure that papers get assigned to you. This is done semi-automatically, assuming your profile is set up properly.

For some reason, the link you mention returns just You are unauthorized to view this page. But I get the point; thanks!

Try https://referees.aps.org/Referrals/login/new

This is what it writes me: ```You are currently logged in with APS Journal account *****
If you have been invited to referee a paper and cannot view this page, please contact help@aps.org for assistance. Typically this is because your APS Journal Account has not yet been properly linked to the referral.```
Maybe something is wrong with my application then...

It should show a login page where you can either log in (if you already have an account) or press "Create an account" if you don't have one yet.

OK, then probably your referee account has not been created yet, you have account as an author but not as a referee. You have to wait when someone sends you a paper for review, as I said, and your accounts will be linked automatically. It could just take time, and the simplest way to speed it up is to ask someone you know to give you the paper they were asked to referee.

As with most such questions about relationships to journals you should ask them. If there is a problem they will let you know, but, I suspect that they would have already done so.
More likely, I think, is that they have made a profile for you (subfield, interests, ...), which takes some time. And, once the profile is complete you won't get a request to review until a paper arrives that fits your profile. Moreover, if they already have several trusted reviewers with a similar profile, it might take even longer for you to get a first request.
I can't promise that this is the actual reason, but if you ask, you will probably learn.
